# How to read query from external file to put in @query for ArangoRepository

Tags: spring-boot, arangodb-java

I am using Spring boot with ArangoRepository for DB connection.

I have a lengthy query with 750 lines and ~118075 characters including comments. Due to which I am facing below error while running code.

`Error java: UTF8 representation for string "LET siteProxyIn = ( ..." is too long for the constant pool`

So, can someone suggest best way to avoid this problem. Or is there a way to load this query from external file to avoid the problem. If so, how can we do it. Can someone share references for this.